# Stripe API: get upcoming invoice for cancelled Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I used this code to cancel stripe subscription with prorate

```
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve(
        $user->subscription('main')->stripe_id
    );

    $subscription->delete([
        'prorate' => true
    ]);
```

in the stripe dashboard subscription cancelled and it is created upcoming invoice with prorate amount.
I want to refund prorate amount to customer's card. I tried to get prorate amount using below code.

```
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($user->subscription('main')->stripe_id);
    $subscription_item = array(
        "id" => $subscription->items->data[0]->id,
        "plan" => $subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id,
        "quantity" => 0,
    );
    $proration_date = time();
    $upcoming_prorated_invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::upcoming([
        "customer" => $subscription->customer,
        "subscription" => $subscription->id,
        "subscription_items" => array($subscription_item),
        "subscription_proration_date" => $proration_date, // optional
    ]);

    dd($upcoming_prorated_invoice);
```

I got below error message

> Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException
>
> You cannot preview the upcoming invoice for a canceled subscription.

**UPDATE**

```
    $subscription->delete([
        'prorate' => true,
        'invoice_now' => true
    ]);

    //$latest_invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($subscription->latest_invoice);
    //$latest_charge_id = $latest_invoice->charge;

    $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve([ 'id' => $subscription->latest_invoice, 'expand' => ['payment_intent.charges'], ]);
    //$charge = $invoice->payment_intent->charges->data[0];
    dd($invoice);
```

payment_intent return as null

Comment: The approach here is not to use the upcoming invoice items API. There's a few ways to approach this. I would explore `prorate: true` and `invoice_now: true`. Then you could finalize the Invoice and your customer's balance will be credited. Then you can look at the proration line items on the invoice and try to Refund this amount by linking it to the original charge on the invoice (you will need to expand the charge). 

Hope that helps!

Comment: @v3nkman I tried what you said. I could not get charge id from last invoice. it is return as null.

Comment: If the last Invoice was successfully paid, then it should have a PaymentIntent [1]. You can expand the PaymentIntent and Charge [2] with the following code with the Invoice ID. 

`
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve([
  'id' => 'in_xxx',
  'expand' => ['payment_intent.charges'],
]);


$charge = $invoice->payment_intent->charges->data[0];
`

Hope that helps!

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-payment_intent

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-charges

Can you compare that with your implementation?

Comment: payment_intent: null

Comment: last invoice subtotal (-60.00) and Amount due is 0. Invoice was finalized and automatically marked as paid because the amount due was $0.00.

Comment: because of zero amount, it is return as null

Comment: @v3nkman I updated code in this question.

Comment: If the amount due on the last Invoice was 0 then there will be no PaymentIntent to drive payment as no charge will be made. I believe that is a different use case to your original question. If you need to refund money based on a proration (unused time on a Subscription) then the last Invoice should have a PaymentIntent.

Comment: customer subscribed to a monthly plan on 1st of June. stripe charge the money from card on same date. then customer decided to cancel subscription on 17th June. I want to refund the money for unused part of the month(18th June to 30th june).  This refund should go to customer card.

Comment: Check out this thread with a solution that worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790776/stripe-api-refund-after-subscription-cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution. 
[ref](https://medium.com/@ismayilkhayredinov/stripe-subscription-cancellation-and-prorated-refund-e4d1b58ff51e)

```
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($user->subscription('main')->stripe_id);

    $proration_date = time();

    $refund = $this->prorate($subscription, $proration_date);

    if ($refund) {
        $latest_invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($subscription->latest_invoice);

        if ($latest_invoice) {
            \Stripe\Refund::create([
                'charge' => $latest_invoice->charge,
                'amount' => $refund,
            ]);
        }
    }



public function prorate(\Stripe\Subscription $subscription, $proration_time)
{
    $period_start = $subscription->current_period_start;
    $period_end = $subscription->current_period_end;
    $amount = $subscription->plan->amount;

    $period_length = $period_end - $period_start;

    $elapsed_since_start = $proration_time - $period_start;

    $refund = $amount - floor(($elapsed_since_start / $period_length) * $amount);

    return $refund > 0 ? (int) $refund : 0;
}
```